# how would i print all the names and scores of those users from a particular class?

Tags: python, sorting, average

let me change the question. how would i extract all of users information(score, class number and score) from a desired class. for e.g i want to know all the users info in lets class number 1.

to help, schooldata[x]['class_code'] = the class number the user types schooldata[x]['score'] = the score obtained by that student 
schooldata[x]['name'] = name of that user
[x] is the student so the first user would be [0], 2nd user [1]                 etc...

```
    schooldata = []
        for x in range (0,3): #the number of loops the quiz is run which is 3 times
            score = 0
            quiz = dict()
            print ("Enter your name")
            quiz['name'] = input()
            print ("what class")
            quiz['class_code'] = input()

            print("1. 9+10=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)

            if answer == 19:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong") 
            print("2. 16+40=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)
            if answer == 56:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong")

            print("3. 5+21=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer) 
            if answer == 26:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong")

            print("4. 5-6=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)
            if answer == -1:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong")

            print("5. 21-9=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)

            if answer == 12:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong")


            print("6. 12-11=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)

            if answer == 1:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong")



            print("7. 5*6=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)

            if answer == 30:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong")



            print("8. 1*8=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)

            if answer == 8:
                print("correct")

                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong")


            print("9. 4*6=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)

            if answer == 24:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1

            else:
                print("wrong")

            print("10. 9*10=")
            answer = input()
            answer = int(answer)

            if answer == 90:
                print("correct")
                score = score + 1
            else:
                print("wrong")
            quiz['score'] = score
            schooldata.append(quiz)


        print ("name - ", schooldata[0]['name'],", user score - ", schooldata[0]['score'],", class number - ", schooldata[0]['class_code'])
        print ("name - ", schooldata[1]['name'],", user score - ", schooldata[1]['score'],", class number - ", schooldata[1]['class_code'])
        print ("name - ", schooldata[2]['name'],", user score - ", schooldata[2]['score'],", class number - ", schooldata[2]['class_code'])

        #high to low
        sorted_schooldata = sorted(schooldata, key=lambda k: k['score'])[::-1]
        #alphabetical
        for i in sorted(schooldata, key=lambda k: k['name']):
            print('%s:%s' %(i['name'], i['score']))
```

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking or what the code snippet has to do with your "question"

Comment: So.. what's the problem? What is your expected vs. actual output? What input do you give your program? Are you getting errors? Don't ask us to do your homework for you. We can help you where you're stuck, but don't ask us to complete the whole assignment.

Comment: You want average score of `schooldata[0]`, `schooldata[1]`, `schooldata[2]`?

Comment: for e.g if i were the teacher and i wanted to know the average score of all the scores in a class. so if the 3 users type in that they are in class number 1 then 2nd user will be class number 2 and say 3rd user types in that they are in class number 1. i as the teacher want to find the average score of all the users in lets say class number 1. so when the teacher types in yes, my code should output name of all users in class number 1 and the average score of that class. hope that makes sense

Comment: It is a huge piece of code. Can you please mention the sample of data structure you are using to store the value and of which value you want the average?

Comment: this is not school work, just mini project i do. expected output = all users in class x (x being the class number), with the users score and then an average score of all users in that class. actual output = i have tried many things but none of them work therefore i have left them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating answer based on updated question:

```
classdata = {}
for data in schooldata:
    if classdata.get(data['class_code']):
        classdata[data['class_code']].append(data)
    else:
        classdata[data['class_code']] = [data]   

print classdata
```

To print class data (in orderly manner):

```
for class_data in sorted(classdata):
   for person_data in sorted(classdata[class_data], key=lambda x: x['name']):
       print person_data['class_code'], person_data['name'], person_data['score']
```

Comment: I hope this is a joke answer.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Any better approach for this? I am not sure what OP wants to know but this answer is based on my understanding of the problem. But I would like to know the better approach to achieve this (which I think you have).

Comment: You edited it into your answer on your own. Don't use `reduce()` unless you have a good reason for it. This isn't one.

Comment: schooldata[x]['class_code'] is where the user stores their class number.

Comment: let me change the question. how would i extract all of users information(score, class number and score) from a desired class. for e.g i want to know all the users info in lets class number 1.

Comment: `>>> classdata = {}
   >>> for data in schooldata:
   >>>   if classdata.get(data['class_code']):
   >>>         classdata[data['class_code']].append(data)
   >>>     else:
   >>>         classdata[data['class_code']] = [data]   

    >>> print classdata` . Here `classdata` will hold the values in the form `dict` with classcode as `key`.

Comment: @jazzy: Was this useful?

Comment: yes however the last user to do the quiz is saved under the first user.

Comment: {'1': [{'name': 'jas', 'score': 1, 'class_code': '1'}]}
{'2': [{'name': 'wqa', 'score': 4, 'class_code': '2'}],                                                 '1': [{'name': 'jas', 'score': 1, 'class_code': '1'}]} this is the code when run. as you can see two users are in class number 1 but only one user is outputted but repeated twice.

Comment: I don't think you have posted the correct output. `{'2': [{'name': 'wqa', 'score': 4, 'class_code': '2'}], '1': [{'name': 'jas', 'score': 1, 'class_code': '1'}]}` is the one output and `{'1': [{'name': 'jas', 'score': 1, 'class_code': '1'}]}` is the another output. A `dict` can not have two same `key`

Comment: Also, please `upvote` the answer and `accept` the answer if it was helpful. :)

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a view whether it fits your requirement

Comment: But did it resolved your problem? And thanks for the accept :)

Comment: yes thank you but i have one question, how would i find the average score for all users in a particualr class? like i want to find out what the average score of class 1 is.

Comment: `sum([class_data['score'] for class_data in classdata['1']])/len( classdata['1'])`